# Custom keyboard instead of default keyboard for all installed android application

Tags: android, ime

I have to display my customized keyboard whenever an edit text in any app is clicked, e.g. in whats-up, to send a message, my custom keyboard should open instead of the default keyboard.

That is a customized keyboard will show in place of the default keyboard in an android device.

Comment: `How can I do? Please suggest any idea`  Here is my idea : use google, try one of the solution you will find and came back here if you have a more precise question.

Comment: @ben75 Thanks for such brilliant idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a custom keyboard and install it with your app.  There is **no** way to automatically get your keyboard to show for all edit fields - this is a security feature built into Android.

The user would have to manually enable your keyboard in settings and then manually switch to it.  The user will also always have the ability to disable and/or uninstall your keyboard and switch to either another custom keyboard or the default Android keyboard.

There are plenty of information on the internet about how to create a custom keyboard - search for it.